# Elements and operation of a monoid

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, inverse, monoid

Let $(X, \star)$ be a monoid, $e\in X$ the identity element and let $x\star x=e$ for all $x\in X$.

Show the following:

1. for all $x\in X$ : $x$ is invertible
2. $\star$ is commutative

$$$$

Could you give me a hint for 1 ? We have that $x\star x=e$ Doesn't this means that $x$ has itself as the inverse element? 
$$$$

As for 2. I have done the following:

Let $x,y\in X$. Thn we get $$x\star x=e \Rightarrow y\star x\star x=y\star e \Rightarrow y\star x\star x=y \Rightarrow y\star x\star x\star x=y\star x \Rightarrow y\star x\star e=y\star x \Rightarrow y\star x=y\star x$$which means that $\star$ is commutative.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: You want to check $x\star y=y\star x$.

Answer (score 1):

You're right about 1. For 2, I'll hide the stars. Since $xyyx=xx=e=xyxy$, the result follows from $xy$ being invertible.

Comment: So 1. is obvious, right? We just say that since $x\star x=e$ each $x$ in $X$ is the inverse of itself, so each $x$ in $X$ is invertible. Is this complete? As for 2. how did you get the term $xyxy$ at the right side of the equation?

Comment: @MaryStar $e=zz$ with $z=xy$.